# Androidapp not building anymore

Tags: android, gradle

When I want to run my Application, I get `Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction`

- I updated all my dependencies
- I increased the RAM of the JVM
- I tried MultiDex
- I cleaned the build
- I invalidated my caches

part of my build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation ('androidx.core:core:1.12.0')  {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'

    //Support
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.4"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1"


    //Graphview
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

}
```

Comment: I changed the `targetSdk` to 34, now I get `Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.12.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.12.0) and support-v4-22.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.12.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.12.0) and support-v4-22.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1)
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get ride of this error. It is very simple just add two lines to your `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```